# Slope Angle between vertices using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, slope

I am trying to work out whether a center pivot irrigator (you may have to google this to see what they look like)  has too much angle between the spans as it goes over hilly terrain.

I can generate 360 lines radiating from the center point and cut the line where the pivot towers are and calculate the slope of each individual line (using vdrape) but how do I calculate the slope angle between each line (or at the line vertex) using QGIS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A graphic / drawing would help to understand the question better.